# Word for Mac: Quickly checking a check box

Tags: ms-office

I have several Word documents with check boxes

[image]

On Windows, you can simply click them to change the status (checked / not checked). But the only way I found to check/uncheck the checkbox with Word 15 or greater for macOS is to double click it and then to switch the value in the form field options:

[image]

Is there a quicker way to change the value?

Answer (score 1):

Buried in the answer to [this previous](https://superuser.com/questions/137936/ms-word-mac-unable-to-use-form-in-document), somewhat related question (from which I liberally cribbed).

1. Go to `Tools`  in the menu.
2. Choose `Protect Document...`
3. Under **Protection**, select `Protect Document for:`
4. Then select `Forms`
5. Hit **OK**

My version of Word for Mac is 16.10.

Comment: This converts the document to a non-editable form. Protecting the document is actually more work then the steps I have to do now ...

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't realize it would create more work for you. I should have asked for more context.

Comment: Actually, this is the answer: the check boxes only work once you "Protect the Form". In the Developer tab, the last item on the right is 'Protect Form'. Select that and your check boxes will work on click. If you do not want to protect the entire form, you need to put in Sections that are not protected. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/using-checkboxes-in-word-for-mac-2016/d48a88bf-c7f2-4795-afbe-6ba7e2bfe7aa?auth=1